# Propel: No database selected

Tags: propel

I'm want to start to use Propel inside my Kohana 3.x Project. But when I try to run the following command:

```
C:\propel\generator\projects\myProject>propel-gen reverse
```

I get the following error:

```
[propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata: SQLSTATE[
3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
[propel-schema-reverse] Schema reverse engineering finished
```

Anybody know how to solve that?

**Additional Information:**

Among others I have the folder myProject containing the build.properties file:

```
C:/propel/generator/projects/myProject/build.properties
```

This is the "sourcecode" of build.properties:

```
propel.project = myProject
propel.database = mysql
propel.database.url = mysql:dbname = myProject;host=localhost
propel.database.user = root
propel.database.password =
```

This is the complete output when I run the command:

```
C:\propel\generator\projects\myProject>propel-gen reverse
Buildfile: C:\propel\generator\bin\..\build.xml
[resolvepath] Resolved C:\propel\generator\projects\myProject to C:\propel\generator\
projects\myProject

propel-project-builder > check-project-or-dir-set:


propel-project-builder > check-project-set:


propel-project-builder > set-project-dir:


propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-exists:


propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-for-propel-gen:


propel-project-builder > check-buildprops:


propel-project-builder > configure:

     [echo] Loading project-specific props from C:\propel\generator\projects\myProject/build.properties
 [property] Loading C:\propel\generator\projects\myProject\build.properties

propel-project-builder > reverse:

    [phing] Calling Buildfile 'C:\propel\generator\build-propel.xml' with target
 'reverse'
 [property] Loading C:\propel\generator\.\default.properties

propel > reverse:

     [echo] +-----------------------------------------------+
     [echo] |                                               |
     [echo] | Generating XML from PDO connection !          |
     [echo] |                                               |
     [echo] +-----------------------------------------------+
[propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata: SQLSTATE[
3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
[propel-schema-reverse] Schema reverse engineering finished

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 0.4205 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in `build.properties` :

```
propel.database.url = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myProject'
```

(following Propel http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/BuildConfiguration#DatabaseSettings and PDO http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php docs)

Comment: Enclose the right hand side by single quotes, otherwise you'll get a warning because parse_ini_file does not support values with '=' in them.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to locate the exact error use the -verbose and -debug mode with propel-gen

```
propel-gen . reverse -verbose -debug
```

as this gives each output of the query that php/propel hits during script execution.